# table view height does not animate properly

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

im using NSTableView which needs to be updated with dynamic height

```
`NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (context) in
        context.duration = 5
        tableView.reloadIndex(tableView.selectedRow)
        tableView.noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged: [tableView.selectedRow])
   }`
```

this is the code i used to animate... first if i try to animate by increasing one cell height the whole table view height increases gradually along with the animation... but again if i selected another cell..... the old selected cell should minimize the height and then increase the height of newly selected cell.... but what happens is... the table view automatically increases the size before cell completely loads and it looks weird (image 1)
[in the image provided you can see how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byhfy.png) (image2) [but i want like this image to increase the height along with cell height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N66yL.png) hope some one helps me in understanding this... im a newbie so please help